# Using Python Regex with Line Count

Tags: python, regex

This is my test code:

```
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
Jacobi
  & $\JacobiP{\alpha}{\beta}{n}@{x}$
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(1 - x)^{\alpha} (1 + x)^{\beta}$
  & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, &\text{$n = 0$} \end{cases}$
  & $\begin{cases} \ifrac{2^{\alpha+\beta+1}\EulerGamma@{\alpha+1}\EulerGamma@{\beta+1}}{\EulerGamma@{\alpha+\beta+2}}, & \text{$n = 0$}\end{cases}$
  & $\dfrac{\pochhammer{n+\alpha+\beta+1}{n}}{2^n n!}$
  & $\dfrac{n (\alpha-\beta)}{2n+\alpha+\beta}$
  & $\alpha,\beta > -1$

  \\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
Ultraspherical(Gegenbauer)
  & $\Ultraspherical{\lambda}{n}@{x}$
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(1 - x^2)^{\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}$
  & $\dfrac{2^{1-2\lambda} \pi \EulerGamma@{n+2\lambda}}
           {(n+\lambda) \left( \EulerGamma@{\lambda} \right)^2 n!}$
  & $\dfrac{2^n \pochhammer{\lambda}{n}}{n!}$ & $0$
  & $\lambda > -\tfrac{1}{2}, \lambda \ne 0 $
\\
```

I have created a pattern to identify the pattern of everything in between "\thinhline \\[-16pt]" and "\\".

How would I find the line count of the lines beginning with ampersands, "&", of the instance of the pattern found?

For example I would want this returned for the sample code:

```
Jacobi: 8
Ultraspherical(Gegenbauer): 6
```

Comment: Does it need to be regex?

Comment: @runDOSrun Not necessarily but I feel like that would be the easiest way.

Comment: @runDOSrun How would I do this? I am a novice to python so I don't how that would work on a ragged array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex `^\s*&` with the `MULTILINE` (`re.M`) flag:

```
import re

text = """
  & $\Ultraspherical{\lambda}{n}@{x}$
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(1 - x^2)^{\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}$
  & $\dfrac{2^{1-2\lambda} \pi \EulerGamma@{n+2\lambda}}
           {(n+\lambda) \left( \EulerGamma@{\lambda} \right)^2 n!}$
  & $\dfrac{2^n \pochhammer{\lambda}{n}}{n!}$ & $0$
  & $\lambda > -\tfrac{1}{2}, \lambda \ne 0 $

"""

print(len(re.findall('^\s*&', text, re.M)))
```

prints 6, which is the number of lines beginning with `&`

Comment: This doesn't differentiate multiple blocks like in op's question, though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "for r in re.finditer(r'(?s)(\\thinhline\n\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([a-zA-Z\s\(\)]+)(.*?)(\n *\\\\)', content):
      x =  len(re.findall('^\s*&', r, re.M))
      print (x)" is returning TypeError: expected string or buffer. The first line is there in order to differentiate between the multiple blocks.

Comment: sorry: had 1 quote character too much from wrong paste, fixed.

Comment: @runDOSrun 'I have created a pattern to identify the pattern of everything in between "\thinhline \\[-16pt]" and "\\".'; the OP has previously answered questions on how to recognize that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import re

s = text.split('\\thinhline\n\\\\[-16pt]\n')[1:]
res = [re.split("\n\s*&", a) for a in s]

[a[0] + ": " + str(len(a)-1) for a in res]
#['Jacobi: 8', 'Ultraspherical(Gegenbauer): 6']
```

Comment: Very nice solution using split.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,line enumerate(my_text.splitlines(),1):
    if line.strip().startswith("&"):
       print line,"On line",i
```

might be what you want ... I dont think regex is the right answer for this